# Mongo DB - Lookup and Count is taking longer to execute

Tags: database, mongodb, database-design, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I am facing slow query execution time issues with MongoDB.

My Basic scenario is, I am developing a Classifieds website on Sails ( Node ) using MongoDB (Linux-x86_64-3.4.4) as Database.

**I have two collections**

1. **ad** - To save advertisement details ( 194419 records / 753.84 mb )
2. **ad_attrs** - To save advertisement attributes details ( 689883 records / 148.75 mb )

We have 2 Different category for users - Personal and Professional. So, we save it to ad collection, Each record contains its type as Personal or Professional.

Now, I want to display total counts of ad based on user's search filters like below

[image: Ad views count by category]

So, I have used below queries to make it possible. but, It been a problem with its performance now.

When I try to Query using Lookup with attrs it's taking **7.5 - 12 Seconds** and When I only Query Ad table it's taking **0.2-1.2 seconds**.

```
db.ad.aggregate(
      [
      {
        "$match":{
          "$and":[
            {
              "is_active":{
                "$eq":1
              }
            },
            {
              "is_delete":{
                "$eq":0
              }
            },
            {
              "is_block":{
                "$eq":0
              }
            },
            {
              "is_online":{
                "$eq":1
              }
            },
            {
              "ad_type":{
                "$eq":"offers"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "$lookup":{
          "from":"ad_attr",
          "localField":"_id",
          "foreignField":"ad_id",
          "as":"attrs"
        }
      },
      {
        "$addFields":{
          "totalAttrs":{
            "$size":"$attrs"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "$project":{
          "ad_user_type":1,
          "attrs":1
        }
      },
      {
        "$group":{
          "_id":null,
          "cnt":{
            "$sum":1
          },
          "pro":{
            "$sum":{
              "$cond":[
                {
                  "$eq":[
                    "$ad_user_type",
                    "professional"
                  ]
                },
                1,
                0
              ]
            }
          },
          "per":{
            "$sum":{
              "$cond":[
                {
                  " $eq":[
                    "$ad_user_type",
                    "personal"
                  ]
                },
                1,
                0
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    ]
    )
```

Collection Structure is as below

**Ad Collection**

```
{
        attributes: {
            _id: {
                type: 'string'
            },
            user_id: {
                type: 'string'
            },
            title: {
                type: 'string'
            },
            description: {
                type: 'longtext'
            },
            price: {
                type: 'float'
            },
            price_max: {
                type: 'float'
            },
            ad_type: {
                type: 'string'
            },
            ad_user_type: {
                type: 'string'
            },
            zipcode: {
                type: 'string'
            },
            lat: {
                type: 'float'
            },
            long: {
                type: 'float'
            },
            loc: {
                type: 'object'
            },
            cityzip: {
                type: 'string'
            },
            town: {
                type: 'string'
            },
            town_slug: {
                type: 'string'
            },
            region: {
                type: 'string'
            },
            region_slug: {
                type: 'string'
            },
            department: {
                type: 'string'
            },
            department_slug: {
                type: 'string'
            },
            address: {
                type: 'longtext'
            },
            telephone: {
                type: 'string'
            },
            is_account_address: {
                type: 'integer',
                defaultsTo: 1
            },
            is_phone_hide: {
                type: 'integer',
                defaultsTo: 0
            },
            video: {
                type: 'string'
            },
            is_video_check: {
                type: 'integer',
                defaultsTo: 0
            },
            is_urgent: {
                type: 'integer',
                defaultsTo: 0
            },
            additional_picture: {
                type: 'integer',
                defaultsTo: 0
            },
            is_in_showcase: {
                type: 'integer',
                defaultsTo: 0
            },
            showcase_date: {
                type: 'date'
            },
            showcase_duration: {
                type: 'string',
                defaultsTo: ""
            },
            showcase_duration_id: {
                type: 'string'
            },
            is_in_top_list: {
                type: 'integer',
                defaultsTo: 0
            },
            top_list_date: {
                type: 'date',
                defaultsTo: ''
            },
            top_list_duration: {
                type: 'string',
                defaultsTo: ""
            },
            top_list_duration_id: {
                type: 'string'
            },
            is_direct_sale: {
                type: 'integer',
                defaultsTo: 0
            },
            is_active: {
                type: 'integer',
                defaultsTo: 0
            },
            is_block: {
                type: 'integer',
                defaultsTo: 0
            },
            post_on_from_backend: {
                type: 'date',
                defaultsTo: ''
            },
            post_on: {
                type: 'date',
                defaultsTo: ''
            },
            post_end_on: {
                type: 'date',
                defaultsTo: ''
            },
            payment_status: {
                type: 'string',
                defaultsTo: 'pending'
            },
            price_token: {
                type: 'string',
            },
            total_views: {
                type: 'integer',
                defaultsTo: 0
            },
            total_clicks: {
                type: 'integer',
                defaultsTo: 0
            },
            is_online: {
                type: 'integer',
                defaultsTo: 0
            },
            is_change_req: {
                type: 'integer',
                defaultsTo: 0
            },
            have_shop: {
                type: 'integer',
                defaultsTo: 0
            },
            shop_id: {
                type: 'string',
                defaultsTo: 0
            },
            slug: {
                type: 'string'
            },
            category: {
                type: 'string'
            },
            category_price: {
                type: 'integer',
                defaultsTo: 0
            },
            parent_category: {
                type: 'string'
            },
            user_ip: {
                type: 'string'
            },
            is_delete: {
                type: 'integer',
                defaultsTo: 0
            },
            product_name: {
                type: 'string'
            },
            product_price: {
                type: 'float',
                defaultsTo: 0
            },
            original_item_quantity: {
                type: 'float',
                defaultsTo: 0
            },
            item_quantity: {
                type: 'float',
                defaultsTo: 0
            },
            shipping_type: {
                type: 'string'
            },
            shipping_value_simple: {
                type: 'float',
                defaultsTo: 0
            },
            shipping_value_variable_min_1: {
                type: 'integer',
                defaultsTo: 0
            },
            shipping_value_variable_max_1: {
                type: 'integer',
                defaultsTo: 0
            },
            shipping_value_variable_1: {
                type: 'float',
                defaultsTo: 0
            },
            shipping_value_variable_min_2: {
                type: 'integer',
                defaultsTo: 0
            },
            shipping_value_variable_max_2: {
                type: 'integer',
                defaultsTo: 0
            },
            shipping_value_variable_2: {
                type: 'float',
                defaultsTo: 0
            },
            shipping_value_variable_min_3: {
                type: 'integer',
                defaultsTo: 0
            },
            shipping_value_variable_max_3: {
                type: 'integer',
                defaultsTo: 0
            },
            shipping_value_variable_3: {
                type: 'float',
                defaultsTo: 0
            },
            seller_paypal_url: {
                type: 'string',
                defaultsTo: ""
            },
            direct_sale_opt_1: {
                type: 'string',
                defaultsTo: ""
            },
            direct_sale_value_1: {
                type: 'longtext',
                defaultsTo: ""
            },
            direct_sale_opt_2: {
                type: 'string',
                defaultsTo: ""
            },
            direct_sale_value_2: {
                type: 'longtext',
                defaultsTo: ""
            },
            direct_sale_opt_3: {
                type: 'string',
                defaultsTo: ""
            },
            have_update: {
                type: 'integer',
                defaultsTo: 0
            },
            update_payment_status: {
                type: 'string',
                defaultsTo: ""
            },
            direct_sale_value_3: {
                type: 'longtext',
                defaultsTo: ""
            },
            attrs: {
                collection: 'ad_attr',
                via: 'ad_id'
            },
            reference: {
                type: 'longtext',
                defaultsTo: ""
            },
            emp_id: {
                type: 'string',
                defaultsTo: "0"
            },
        },
    }
```

**Ad Attribtues Collection**

```
attributes: {
    ad_id:{
      model:'ad'
    },
    cat_id:{
      type:'string',
    },
    attr_id:{
      type:'string',
    },
    value:{
      type:'string',
    },
    integer_value:{
      type:'float',
      defaultsTo: 0,
    }
  }
```

**Index Added for Collections**
Ad - I have added indexes to all attributes those are used for Condition

```
Id , loc , post_on, price, ad_type, is_delete, is_active, is_online, is_block, ad_user_type, attrs, category, parent_category, region_slug, department_slug, town_slug, slug
```

Ad Attributes

```
Id, attr_id, value, ad_id, attrs
```

**Server Configurations** - It's fine for the current database size

- 100 GB SSD
- 8 GB RAM
- 4 Core Processor

**I have done so far**
 - Google for all possibilities
 - Removing attributes those are not needs to query for count and list

**I want you to help me with below questions**

1. Shall I improve my Collection structure to make it faster?
2. Shall I move some attributes to another collection, which are not used to Query for count?
3. Shall I need to upgrade Mongo config settings or what?
4. Shall I need to upgrade my server hardware?

Experts, I need your help to resolve this. Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: Your question is quite good. However, Can you update to give more information about explain of your query https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.explain/ ? One more thing can you describe more detail about indexes ? You create 1 index for all columns you specify or each columns you create 1 index

Comment: Is there a specific reason why the ad attributes are stored in a separate collection?

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg Yes, Actually each Ad Post can be from a different category. Like It can be a car or a mobile phone. Also, Each attribute can be dynamically manageable from the admin panel. So, It's better we save attributes in a separate table. :)

Comment: @KhánhBùiĐức Sure, Let me also attach query's Explain result. Currently, I have creared 1 Index per Column.

Comment: what is your mongodb version? and please post some sample collection and the output... And instead of `$group` use single `$project` at the end of the pipeline and for count use a separate query